# BGInfo fails to record free diskspace on Windows 10 64Bit because no JET installed

Tags: excel, wmic, diskspace

**My goal is to graph a PC's disk free space over time in Excel.** BGinfo worked on Windows 10 32bit to write to a text file each time it ran. I recently changed the disks in the machine and upgraded the windows to 64Bit at the same time.

Now BGinfo displays info on the desktop, but fails when trying to write to the text file. The error is:

> "Database Support requires that Jet4.0 or later be installed. (Jet 0.0 detected)".

The machine is a headless box that runs overnight backups so it doesn't have Excel/Access which I think would install MDAC and Jet.

**First - can I install JET4.0 on the machine?** This would be ideal as the text file and spreadsheet would work without changes.

If JET is no-go **how else can I generate a text file with the information I need?** Something like this:

`Date, Time, PC Name, Vol1, Vol1 Size, Vol1 Free Space, Vol2, Vol 2 Size, Vol 2 Free Space,
20191121,14:40:30,BACKUP-BOX,C:,931.12GB,555.55GB,E:,1800.00GB, 1234.56GB`

I've looked a bit at WMIC but that generates multi-line output and I don't want to reinvent the wheel if there's an easier way.

`wmic /node:"%COMPUTERNAME%" LogicalDisk Where DriveType="3" Get Name,DeviceID,Size,FreeSpace /format:csv`

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else with this issue:

The BGinfo download package includes two executables.

Both of them work fine to update the desktop info, but only Bginfo.exe (32bit) can write the data to Test/XLS/SQL file.

BGinfo64.exe throws up the MDAC / JET error that prompted my original question.